# What is the mouse shape of "The Mouse's Tale" in Alice?

Tags: poetry

["The Mouse's Tale"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mouse%27s_Tale) is a shaped poem by Lewis Carroll which appears in his 1865 novel Alice's Adventures in Wonderland.

I read in [Mouse Tale (Fall 91)](https://www1.udel.edu/PR/Messenger/92/1/49.html):

> Traditional tail-rhymes have a shorter "caudal line" or tail than the couplets that precede it. Apparently, in the revised version, Carroll deliberately lengthened the caudal lines in the four stanzas of his mouse's poem so that, if printed traditionally, the tale would take the shape of a mouse with a long tail.

So I arranged the Mouse's Tale in that tail-rhyme shape, but could not see the shape of a mouse:

```
"Fury said to a mouse, 
that he met in the house, 
'Let us both go to law: I will prosecute you - 

Come, I'll take no denial; 
We must have a trial: 
For really this morning I've nothing to do.' 

Said the mouse to the cur, 
'Such a trial, dear Sir, 
with no jury or judge, would be wasting our breath.' 

'I'll be judge, I'll be jury,' 
Said cunning old Fury: 
'I'll try the whole cause, and condemn you to death.'"
```

Where is the mouse?

Comment: As printed at your link, there is no mouse body to look at, only a ridiculously long and wiggly tail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because fanciful orthography is not nuts-and-bolts language.

Comment: Presumably the two short lines and the first half of the long line are the body and the end of the long line is the tail.

Comment: From the article: "the line structure of the triplets (two short lines, then a longer line) resembles the shape of a mouse." You have four "mice" above. Body body tail. Body body tail. Body body tail. Body body tail.

Comment: It's [this shape!](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Flookaside.fbsbx.com%2Flookaside%2Fcrawler%2Fmedia%2F%3Fmedia_id%3D3288561514537418&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F277717528955180%2Fposts%2Fthe-mouses-tale-is-a-shaped-poem-by-lewis-carroll-which-appears-in-his-novel-ali%2F3288561541204082%2F&tbnid=8ZP6bZuz2jlLdM&vet=12ahUKEwi8iIyx1Ov1AhW8lP0HHW1nDt4QMygEegQIARBj..i&docid=J9FXEcaOavvdtM&w=454&h=675&itg=1&q=0%20%22The%20Mouse%27s%20Tale%22%20is%20a%20shaped%20poem%20by%20Lewis%20Carroll&ved=2ahUKEwi8iIyx1Ov1AhW8lP0HHW1nDt4QMygEegQIARBj)

Comment: (Do a google search for **The Mouse's Tale** with **Images** checked.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is the actual page from the actual original version.

Comment: Usual furore about something a little unusual. I am reminded of a limerick: There was young man from Japan, Whose lines just would not scan, When told it was so, He said yes I know, But I like to get as many words into the last line as I can.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/1991/05/01/books/tale-in-tail-s-a-study-worthy-of-alice-s-friends.html

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That was my first thought too, but the second link provided by the OP seems to be referring to a _different_ version from the familiar 'wiggly tail' as printed in the book. Having looked up _tail-rhyme_ (a line of markedly different length from the rest of the verse), I realised what the author must mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That isn't  how it looks 'if printed traditionally' though.

Comment: @Spagirl: I don't remember ever reading a "traditionally" printed version of this poem. I certainly can't imagine any printer failing to typeset it correctly in its proper context (the actual book *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*). The actual text immediately preceding the "poem" in AAIW is *...so that her* [Alice's] *idea of the tale was **something like this...*** - which would clearly be meaningless if the page layout didn't reflect Carroll's intentions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers of course it would. I didn't say anything about how it was usually, or even invariably printed. The changes to the poem mean *if it were printed  'as a  'tail-rhyme' traditionally is*,  rather than as this particular poem was initially  and primarily designed to be printed, it would look a bit like a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse is found in the shape of the prose. Here are three versions of your first verse: the original; a blurred version; and a very blurred version.

[image]

The final blurred version vaguely suggests a crouching mouse with its tail extending behind. And here for comparison is a mouse sketch:

[image]

Comment: So, the OP distorted the poem's graphic shape and now doesn't recognize the shape created?

Comment: But guesses can be wrong (and are inappropriate on ELU).

Comment: No, no, no. https://hornbakelibrary.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/the-mouses-tale/

Comment: @YosefBaskin: No. It seems Carroll wrote it such that the last line of each stanza would be longer, resembling a tail. It also seems that no one here bothered reading the article: https://www.nytimes.com/1991/05/01/books/tale-in-tail-s-a-study-worthy-of-alice-s-friends.html

Answer (score 0):

> "The Mouse's Tale"

= a ***tale*** (story) told by a mouse.

The mouse's ***tail*** = the tail attached to the mouse.

The poem is part of a ***tale*** told by a mouse and is in the shape of the ***tail*** attached to the mouse.

Here's another shaped poem:

## [image: Rain]

Comment: And it's HERE, not in your picture. Haven't you ever seen an original of Alice in Wonderland?? https://hornbakelibrary.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/the-mouses-tale/